# Interpolation in Snowflake. Anyone know if this is possible via some kind of inbuilt function (or otherwise)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, interpolation

The frequency my input data (timestamps) are non-uniform in distribution. I'm hoping to use interpolation to make the x axis uniform.

So far, I can't find anything in the Snowflake documentation.

Input:
[image]

Comment: I have worked on various approaches and have seen work from others along these lines. The approach may vary depending on the details of the requirements. Can you provide a minimal sample of data and expected outputs?

Comment: I'm measuring pollution levels across different cities (values are timestamped). I've included a sample of the data input (edited- please see above). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach -

Below date CTE has non-uniform dates.

Idea is -
We get min date and max date from the data-set.
Next, we find number of days between max and min dates.
Next, we calculate how many days to add starting from min date to genenerate interpolated data-set for dates.
For table generator we have to give a constant, hence we use a large number and use qualify to stop at the number of dates needed.

```
with date_cte(dates) as
(select * from values
('2022-01-12'::date),
('2022-02-12'::date),
('2022-02-19'::date),
('2022-03-11'::date),
('2022-04-10'::date),
('2022-04-12'::date),
('2022-05-02'::date),
('2022-06-14'::date),
('2022-06-28'::date)
), agg_cte as (
select dates, 
max(dates) over (order by null) mx ,
min(dates) over (order by null)  mn,
count(*) over (order by null)  cnt,
datediff(day,mn,mx) days_btwn, days_btwn/(cnt-1) days_incr 
from date_cte)
select a.dates,
a.mn,
a.mx,
a.days_btwn,
a.days_incr
,row_number() over(order by seq4()) rn,
dateadd(day,a.days_incr * (rn-1), a.mn) interpolated_dates
from agg_cte a,table(generator(rowcount=>10000)) 
qualify row_number() over (order by null)<=cnt
order by interpolated_dates asc;
```

Will yield following data-set (refer column INTERPOLATED_DATES) -

| DATES | MN | MX | DAYS_BTWN | DAYS_INCR | RN | INTERPOLATED_DATES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 1 | 2022-01-12 |
| 2022-02-12 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2 | 2022-02-02 |
| 2022-02-19 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 3 | 2022-02-23 |
| 2022-03-11 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 4 | 2022-03-16 |
| 2022-04-10 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 5 | 2022-04-06 |
| 2022-04-12 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 6 | 2022-04-26 |
| 2022-05-02 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 7 | 2022-05-17 |
| 2022-06-14 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 8 | 2022-06-07 |
| 2022-06-28 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 9 | 2022-06-28 |

Updated (included cities) answer -

```
with date_cte(dates,cities) as
(select * from values
('2022-01-12'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-02-12'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-02-19'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-03-11'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-04-10'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-04-12'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-05-02'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-06-14'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-06-28'::date,'citi-1'),
('2022-01-11'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-02-12'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-02-19'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-03-11'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-04-10'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-04-12'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-05-02'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-06-14'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-07-11'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-06-28'::date,'citi-2'),
('2022-01-07'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-02-12'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-02-19'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-03-11'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-04-10'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-04-12'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-05-02'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-06-14'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-06-28'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-06-30'::date,'citi-3'),
('2022-07-21'::date,'citi-3')
), agg_cte as (
select cities,dates, 
row_number() over(partition by cities order by null) rn,
max(dates) over (partition by cities order by null) mx ,
min(dates) over (partition by cities order by null)  mn,
count(*) over (partition by cities order by null)  cnt,
datediff(day,mn,mx) days_btwn, days_btwn/(cnt-1) days_incr 
from date_cte)
select a.cities,
a.dates,
a.mn,
a.mx,
a.days_btwn,
a.days_incr,
dateadd(day,a.days_incr * (rn-1), a.mn) interpolated_dates
from agg_cte a
order by cities,interpolated_dates,dates asc;
```

| CITIES | DATES | MN | MX | DAYS_BTWN | DAYS_INCR | INTERPOLATED_DATES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| citi-1 | 2022-02-12 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-01-12 |
| citi-1 | 2022-02-19 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-02-02 |
| citi-1 | 2022-03-11 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-02-23 |
| citi-1 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-03-16 |
| citi-1 | 2022-04-12 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-04-06 |
| citi-1 | 2022-05-02 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-04-26 |
| citi-1 | 2022-06-14 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-05-17 |
| citi-1 | 2022-06-28 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-06-07 |
| citi-1 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-06-28 | 167 | 20.875000 | 2022-06-28 |
| citi-2 | 2022-05-02 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-01-11 |
| citi-2 | 2022-06-28 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-01-31 |
| citi-2 | 2022-07-11 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-02-20 |
| citi-2 | 2022-06-14 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-03-12 |
| citi-2 | 2022-04-12 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-04-01 |
| citi-2 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-04-22 |
| citi-2 | 2022-03-11 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-05-12 |
| citi-2 | 2022-02-19 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-06-01 |
| citi-2 | 2022-02-12 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-06-21 |
| citi-2 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-07-11 | 181 | 20.111111 | 2022-07-11 |
| citi-3 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-01-07 |
| citi-3 | 2022-02-12 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-01-27 |
| citi-3 | 2022-02-19 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-02-15 |
| citi-3 | 2022-03-11 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-03-07 |
| citi-3 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-03-26 |
| citi-3 | 2022-04-12 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-04-15 |
| citi-3 | 2022-05-02 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-05-04 |
| citi-3 | 2022-06-14 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-05-24 |
| citi-3 | 2022-06-28 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-06-12 |
| citi-3 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-07-02 |
| citi-3 | 2022-07-21 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-07-21 | 195 | 19.500000 | 2022-07-21 |

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. But would would you do this across with an added layer of complexity. Say you were measuring the pollution at given time stamps across multiple cities. The 'Dates' column would contain values from different cities (non-uniform x value). How could that be made to work?

Comment: Like @Greg also mentioned in his comment, it helps if you post some sample data and expected output. Without that its hard for anyone trying to answer. For cities with dates perhaps you need to use partition dates over cities.